# Where should I keep global state in frontend about Next.js?

Tags: cookies, next.js, state, recoiljs

Where should I keep global state in frontend about Next.js?
I know cookie is one of the solutions, but are there any other good ways?

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2252#issuecomment-308238001

Comment: Is there a reason cookies aren't enough for you? That's the go-to solution when you need to persist data on the frontend. Alternatively you can use local storage, but cookies are still preferable to that.

Comment: Thank you! I see, and that's enough but I wanted to know every choices before deciding.